# IS there a connection between the Gods of Aqua and Fuero and the Holy Maidens of Metafalss?

Tags: ar-tonelico

So as i was playing *Ar Tonelico Qoga: Knell of Ar Ciel* when someone comments that Sarapatra's name is that of the Goddess of Love, in the glossary an entry of deities appear. in it it talks about Elemental Gods such as the God of Aqua and the God of Fuero.

Considering that in Metafalss Luca and Nenesha are known as the Maidens of Fuero and Cloche and Infel are the Maidens of Aqua, is there a connection between the Gods of Aqua and Fuero and the Holy Maidens of Metafalss which was not mentioned in Ar Tonelico 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't. "Aqua" and "Fuero" are no more than horrible mistranslations that NISA made of the words "Mio" and "Homura", which translate to "Waterway" and "Flame", and in the case of AT3, that glossary entry refers to the Gods of Fire and Water.

As for the Maidens, their names are just references to the roles they have when it comes to singing Metafalica: the Maiden of Mio is the Maiden that has the role of serving as the waterway that collects the feelings of all the IPDs into one, while the Maiden of Homura has the role of turning these feelings into a flame (energy) with the power necessary to cross the wave flow and spectrum requirements that Metafalica needs to be executed successfully.